# Event callback with responsive sliders

Tags: jquery, slider

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I'm really haveing an hard time figuring this out.

My problem: 
To create a jquery slideshow (i tried using woothemes flexslider first, and ResponsiveSlides then) with some callback function so that, upon slide change, my background color fades into another background color (as specified in a Wordpress custom field, but that's not an issue)

I did it with Flexslider at first, but for some reason my thingy works if i don't add any bkgnd animation

```
before: function(slider) {
  animate = 'bg'+slider.animatingTo;
  $('body').addClass(animate);
  current = 'bg'+slider.currentSlide;
  $('body').removeClass(current);
}
```

if i add an animation like addClass(animate, 1000) for some reason the fading works good going forward, and doesn't work going backwards (i guess it can't understand where it is animating to, when you go backwards)

So I tried doing this in responsiveslides, but since there is no API, i'm just trying to fill the before: function with some code to achieve what I need.

ANy suggestion would be GREATLY appreciated!